# katalon test case if sql query return correct value

Tags: katalon-studio

i have data files/database which query all items in `table 1 (table 1 has column A, B, C)`
[image]

```
SELECT * from DB1.table1
```

then test case

> 1. get data from data files
>
>    **def data = findTestData('Data Files/Database')**
> 2. find value 123 in column A, then check column C if 0 passed, if not 0 then failed. earlier codes works. as below codes and result.
> 3. now, there is issue that 123 may appear multiple times in column A, how to enhance codes to check only the latest value by using datatime column?

```html
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData

import com.kms.katalon.core.logging.KeywordLogger
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData as TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.util.KeywordUtil

def KeywordLogger result = KeywordUtil.logInfo()

TestData data = findTestData('Data Files/Database')



for(i=1; i<= data.getRowNumbers(); i++){
 if(data.getValue(1, i)=='123'){
  println data.getValue(3,i)
  assert data.getValue(3,i) == '0'
  KeywordUtil.markPassed("test passed")
 }
}
```

test case result, actual: 123 value is 0. test result passed.

```html
    2019-09-26 09:40:55.333 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - --------------------
    2019-09-26 09:40:55.335 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - START Test Cases/DatabaseTest/Get DB data - Copy - Copy
    2019-09-26 09:40:55.602 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 1: result = logInfo()
    2019-09-26 09:40:55.605 INFO  com.kms.katalon.core.util.KeywordUtil    - null
    2019-09-26 09:40:55.607 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 2: data = findTestData("Data Files/Database")
    2019-09-26 09:40:55.904 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.db.DatabaseConnection   - dbServerInfo = PostgreSQL 11.5 (Debian 11.5-1.pgdg90+1)
    2019-09-26 09:40:55.939 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 3: for ([i = 1, i <= data.getRowNumbers(), (i++)])
    2019-09-26 09:40:55.954 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 1: if (data.getValue(1, i) == "123")
    2019-09-26 09:40:56.042 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 1: if (data.getValue(1, i) == "123")
    2019-09-26 09:40:56.043 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 1: if (data.getValue(1, i) == "123")
    2019-09-26 09:40:56.044 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 1: if (data.getValue(1, i) == "123")
    2019-09-26 09:40:56.045 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 1: println(data.getValue(3, i))
    true
    2019-09-26 09:40:56.050 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 2: assert data.getValue(3, i) == "0"
    2019-09-26 09:40:56.054 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 3: markPassed("test passed")
    2019-09-26 09:40:56.057 DEBUG com.kms.katalon.core.util.KeywordUtil    - ✓ test passed
    2019-09-26 09:40:56.058 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 1: if (data.getValue(1, i) == "123")
    2019-09-26 09:40:56.059 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 1: if (data.getValue(1, i) == "123")
    2019-09-26 09:40:56.060 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 1: if (data.getValue(1, i) == "123")
    2019-09-26 09:40:56.062 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - END Test Cases/DatabaseTest/Get DB data - Copy - Copy
```

then i changed the 123 to 234. actual: 234 is not 0. then test case failed.

```
2019-09-26 09:44:38.155 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - --------------------
2019-09-26 09:44:38.157 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - START Test Cases/DatabaseTest/Get DB data - Copy - Copy
2019-09-26 09:44:38.403 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 1: result = logInfo()
2019-09-26 09:44:38.408 INFO  com.kms.katalon.core.util.KeywordUtil    - null
2019-09-26 09:44:38.409 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 2: data = findTestData("Data Files/Database")
2019-09-26 09:44:38.681 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.db.DatabaseConnection   - dbServerInfo = PostgreSQL 11.5 (Debian 11.5-1.pgdg90+1)
2019-09-26 09:44:38.709 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 3: for ([i = 1, i <= data.getRowNumbers(), (i++)])
2019-09-26 09:44:38.722 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 1: if (data.getValue(1, i) == "234")
2019-09-26 09:44:38.798 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 1: if (data.getValue(1, i) == "234")
2019-09-26 09:44:38.799 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 1: if (data.getValue(1, i) == "234")
2019-09-26 09:44:38.801 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 1: if (data.getValue(1, i) == "234")
2019-09-26 09:44:38.802 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 1: println(data.getValue(3, i))
false
2019-09-26 09:44:38.806 DEBUG testcase.Get DB data - Copy - Copy       - 2: assert data.getValue(3, i) == "0"
2019-09-26 09:44:38.826 ERROR c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - ❌ Test Cases/DatabaseTest/Get DB data - Copy - Copy FAILED.
Reason:
Assertion failed: 

assert data.getValue(3,i) == '0'
       |    |          |  |
       |    false      43 false
       com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.DBData@79145d5a

 at Get DB data - Copy - Copy.run(Get DB data - Copy - Copy:16)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:337)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:328)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:307)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:299)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:233)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:105)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
 at TempTestCase1569462275661.run(TempTestCase1569462275661.groovy:21)

2019-09-26 09:44:38.838 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - END Test Cases/DatabaseTest/Get DB data - Copy - Copy
```

Comment: show data sample, and show table structure sample.

Comment: added sample database table

Comment: @user2201789 After changing '123' to '234' second row is selected and the third column of that row has the value of '1', and you are asserting '0'. So, the test case correctly failed.

Comment: @MateMrše yes, u are right. thats my intention to make it failed. my new issue is that with 2 value of '123', how do i just validate the latest '123' based on last column datatime?

Comment: That would be more complicated. As things are now, the row by row will be checked for the value '123' and then the third column compared to '0'. So the first '123' assert = 0 will pass, and the second time '123' appears assert = 0 will fail. Is this not enough?

Comment: @MateMrše alright, if it is complicated. i guess current test case is good enough. thanks!

Comment: @user2201789 No problem. If this was helpful you might consider upvoting my answer (if it was helpful) and accepting it (if it solved your problem). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet will do what you wanted, provided the test data table `'Data Files/Database'` in the example is an excel table (not sure how to do the same with database):

```
def data = findTestData("Data Files/Database")

for(i=1; i<= data.getRowNumbers(); i++){
    if(data.getObjectValue(1, i)=='123'){
        println data.getObjectValue(3,i)
        assert data.getObjectValue(3,i) != '0'
    }
}
```

Comment: is getRowNumbers and getObjectValue can be used here, if the column A , value 123 sometimes appear at row 1, sometimes row 2? how to not find the fixed row instead of find the value in column?

Comment: The for loop will search the first column, row by row. When it finds the value '123' it will enter the if() part and then assert the value of the third column of that row is not 0.

Comment: Got it. After assert. Can I use built in util to printit or marked.passed else marked.failed?

Comment: Yes you can. But no use for mark failed, if assert fails the test automatically fails.

Comment: i changed the getObjectValue to getValue, and changed assert != '0' to == '0'. result looks good. updated main post. thanks for advise!

Comment: i updated again main post, now, there is issue that 123 may appear multiple times in column A, how to enhance codes to check only the latest value by using datatime column?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking somekind of IF condtion to show something

```
 select t.a ,t.b,
     IF( t.c = 1 , "SUCCESS", "FAIL")  as status

 from table as t
```

Comment: thanks. more likely but katalon use different keyword/syntax. i'm not sure what to use.